# How to type proper Italian using QWERTY keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, input-languages

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY), you cannot write 100% Italian on a QWERTY keyboard but I am wondering how you would write Italian with a QWERTY keyboard then? For example, characters like ë, ï, and é are a huge pain since I currently have to keep opening Character Map, find the symbol, copy it, then switch windows and paste.

Comment: erm... dead keys? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set your keyboard layout to us-international you can use the so called "dead"-keys.

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> followed by <kbd>e</kbd> to get ë.

Also
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> /
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> /
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> /
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>
followed by the desired letter.

Way better then remembering those alt-combinations.

Keyboard layout is under configuration, keyboard an languages, change keyboard..under italy add us-international and set as default above in the pulldown. Choose apply and remove the other layout (presumably italian)¡
If you don't remove the italian you could accidentaly change back with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> or some other combo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Alt codes. For example, for ë you would hold Alt and press numbers zero, two, three and then five in sequence (not at the same time), then release Alt. I *believe* you can use the top-row numbers, but I always used to use the Number Pad.

A full list is here: http://www.alt-codes.net

Comment: Thank you @Craig, do you know of any Italian keyboards that I could buy (if they even exist)? I find using ALT+ to be very tedious and it interrupts my flow and concentration at times.

Comment: Unfortunately there are none that I can immediately find. That said, your next best option is to change the keyboard layout in Windows to Italian (from memory - I haven't touched a Windows machine's regional settings in a long time - it should be somewhere in Control Panel) and either make/buy a set of key covers for your QWERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Just select italian keyboard on the operating system - some keys will behave differently (eg: you press [ but get è), but eventually you will get used, I always type Italian with English keyboard.